# Optimized way to get a position list of a bit list

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

Is anybody out there who have a more efficient/faster way to get a list of all 1-bit-positions in an integer? I have this:

```
array_keys(
    str_split(
        strrev(
            decbin(1234)
        )
    ), '1', true
)
```

The output is:

```
array(1, 4, 6, 7, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with regex, but I bet your solution is better.

```
preg_match_all('/1/', strrev(decbin(1234)), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$output = array_map(function($item){
  return $item[1];
}, $matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 4
  2 => int 6
  3 => int 7
  4 => int 10
```

Answer (score 0):

More faster than string and array operations are the bits operations:

```
$x = 1234;
$ak = array();
$i = 0;

while ($x)
{
    if ( $x % 2 )
    {
        $ak[] = $i;
    }

    $i++;
    $x = $x >> 1;
}

print_r($ak);
```

Here you have more lines of code, but it is faster...